# Why does the UK use US-made strategic missiles?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, weapons

Why does the United Kingdom use strategic missiles made in the United States, such as Trident, instead of producing their own? It is understandable that they would import tactical missiles, but why would they need to import strategic missiles?

Comment: I have a feeling the answer is more economic than political, as is 90% of questions like this.

Comment: Why shouldn't they use the technology that a strong ally made?

Comment: Why do we have nuclear missiles at all? At least buying them from the US is a collossal waste of a slightly less collossal sum of money.

Comment: @MichaelKay We have nuclear missiles because others have them too. I know it's MAD but that's how the world and humans work.

Comment: Part of the world and a few of its humans.

Comment: Needs more details. Please clarify the difference between tactical and strategic missile and why you think UK shouldn't be importing *strategic* missiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your repeated comments under other answers, you seem to invite a comparison with France: the 1st gen US sub-launched nuclear missiles were substantially more difficult to deal with than the 1st gen French one, and by that I mean by an adversary.

Polaris [had] 3 warheads and 2,500 miles range. The French [M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M1_(missile)) had a single warhead and 1,900 miles range.

Sharing tech with the US meant the UK got something better, probably faster than they would have developed it on their own. Also, the UK did not completely buy into the US system, as they got their warheads built to their [own specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ET.317), albeit mostly by mixing and matching other existing US designs. (Still, the resulting warhead necessitated its own test in Nevada, to validate.)

Once the Soviets deployed their ABM missiles, the number of (simulated) warheads became even more of a thing. To maintain credible penetration of Moscow's defenses in case they had to deal with the Soviets alone, the UK deployed [special versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevaline) of the Polaris re-entry vehicle, which reduced the number of warheads to two, but added some 30 penetration aids to confuse enemy radars. This would have been next to impossible on a single-warhead missile (like the French had at the time on their subs).

After that the UK pretty much got its current iteration of sub-launched missile--the Trident D5, which is 2nd gen Trident, essentially having skipped the first gen Trident. The D5 has has 3-8 real warheads. Its range depends on the number of warheads; with just 3 it can can basically reach Vladivostok from UK territorial waters, and it can launch 8 warheads at Moscow from the same area. France got [6-warhead] MIRVs on their sub-launched missiles around the same time [(M4 in 1985)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(missile)), but they were clearly unhappy with the 1,900 miles range, so built something like the 5th (M45) and 6th generation (M51) later on, with improved range. Wikipedia doesn't publish production numbers for most of these, but if they were anything like the 3rd gen (M20) for which 100 were built, you can guess that France probably spent twice as much materials, if not money going through all these developments/iterations.

Accuracy-wise, the claimed CEP of the French M51 is still worse than the decades old Trident D5. On the same generation level, the French M4 has a published CEP about 2-3 times worse than the Trident D5. (If you wonder why this matters, accuracy is quite important against hardened targets--see fig.1 on p.25 in the 1986 CBO [docs](https://www.cbo.gov/sites/default/files/99th-congress-1985-1986/reports/doc18b-entire_0.pdf), which relates psi-pressure rating of a bunker to warhead accuracy. Only the [super-expensive] MX/Peacekeeper with its famous beryllium sphere floating in fluorocarbons guidance was more accurate than the D5. The Reagan administration thought it worthwhile to make the Soviet leadership worry about possibly being killed before they made it to the deepest levels of their bunkers--just in case they didn't care enough about the fate of their cities/citizens in the event of a nuclear war. It's one of the reasons the US pursued increased accuracy for the 2nd gen Tridents, i.e. the one currently deployed by US & UK.)

So, yeah, catching up or keeping up with the US is possible on such tech, but in some regards it appears it has taken France substantially longer than if you simply check the box "nuclear-sub missile" without paying attention to certain specifics.

And to add a bit more historical-political meat to that... I was able find out [that](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2016/feb/11/trident-the-british-question)

> [Defence minister John] Nott could boast in 1982 that Trident’s cost over 15 years would be about 3% of the UK’s annual defence budget – compared to the 20% of annual defence spending that an independent deterrent was costing the French.

So, yeah, the UK public was apparently sold on this kind of cost benefit as well. Furthermore (same source), Thacher even agreed that servicing the Trident missile on-shore would be done exclusively in the US (unlike for Polaris) because “the political and financial advantages of carrying out missile processing in the United States outweighed the marginal reduction in the independence of the Trident system and the eventual loss of job opportunities in Scotland”.

Answer (score 9):

The UK estimated that developing submarine launched ballistic missile technology on their own would have cost a whole lot of money and would have taken at least 15 years. This option was quickly eliminated. They then debated partnering with France or the US. Despite two wars between the US and the UK a couple of centuries ago, the two countries have become staunch allies. Partnering with the US won out versus partnering with France.

Comment: How did France manage to do that?

Comment: @user366312 By having a state-owned aerospace company that already built powerful rockets such as the Ariane 5.

Comment: Why and how did the UK lag in this area?

Comment: @user366312 Cynical explanation: They chased their rocket scientists out thanks to British astronomers who thought that having Parliament ban British participation in human spaceflight would be a good idea. Britain had slipped quite a bit in aerospace in general before this ban was retracted. Non-cynical explanation: They invested their limited defense funding in other arenas.

Comment: Add these comments in the answer, please.

Comment: @user366312 de Gaulle was suspicious of the Americans and so wanted to be able to operate independently of them. British leaders favoured closer ties with the USA and were content with a semi-independent nuclear deterrent. Both countries had the technical ability to develop SLBMs, but only France had the political impulse to do so.

Comment: @user366312 How France managed that but the UK didn't is a different question. It would be better if you asked that question as a new question.

Comment: @user366312 It’s worth noting that France has been, since WWI, actually more militarily independent than many other European states. They kept using their own custom assault rifle designs until 2017 (they’re now shifting to H&K models), they continue to use their own locally developed tanks (putting them in an exclusive club with Italy, Germany, Turkey and the UK, everyone else in Europe is using German, UK, or Russian derivatives or borrowing stock from one of the above), etc. IOW, France actually has a pretty strong local military industrial complex for a European state.